# Team Auto answering Machine

Tags: powershell

The error messages suggest that there are issues with the script importing the necessary modules and finding the necessary files. Specifically:

The error message "The specified module 'Microsoft.OutlookAutomation' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory" suggests that the required PowerShell module "Microsoft.OutlookAutomation" is not installed on your system. You can try installing it using the command "Install-Module Microsoft.OutlookAutomation" in PowerShell.

The error message "The term 'Get-OutlookItem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" suggests that the module "Microsoft.OutlookAutomation" is not being loaded correctly in the script. You can try adding the line "Import-Module Microsoft.OutlookAutomation" at the beginning of the script to ensure that the module is loaded.

The error message "Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Lenny\Documents\TeamsAutoCall\TeamsAutoCall.log' because it does not exist" suggests that the log file that the script is trying to read from does not exist in the specified location. You can try creating the file manually before running the script or modifying the script to create the file if it does not exist.

This Script belongs doing this

Here's a breakdown of what the script does:

Selects all the content in each Microsoft Teams window.
Checks if there is an incoming call and automatically answers it.
Schedules calls based on the Teams meetings on the user's calendar.
Initiates the call 5 minutes before the meeting start time and ends the call 9 minutes after the scheduled end time of the meeting.
Checks if the call is still active and recalls the person if the call was disconnected before the end time.
Waits for 1 minute before checking again.

```
  # Select all content in each Teams window
    $teamsarray = (Get-Process *teams*).Id
    foreach ($obj in $teamsarray) {
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
        $Result = $wshell.AppActivate($obj)
        $Result2 = $wshell.SendKeys('^+A')
    }
    
    # Check if there is an incoming call and auto-answer it
    $callStatus = (Get-Content -Tail 100 $Log | Select-String -Pattern "Incoming call")
    if ($callStatus) {
        $teamsarray = (Get-Process *teams*).Id
        foreach ($obj in $teamsarray) {
            $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
            $Result = $wshell.AppActivate($obj)
            $Result2 = $wshell.SendKeys('^+M')
        }
    }
    
    # Schedule calls based on the Teams meetings
    $currentTime = Get-Date
    foreach ($meeting in $TeamsMeetings) {
        # Calculate the meeting start time and check if it's time to initiate the call
        $meetingStart = $meeting.Start.AddMinutes(-5) # Start the call 5 minutes before the meeting start time
        if ($currentTime -ge $meetingStart -and $currentTime -lt $meeting.Start) {
            # Initiate the call
            $teamsarray = (Get-Process *teams*).Id
            foreach ($obj in $teamsarray) {
                $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
                $Result = $wshell.AppActivate($obj)
                $Result2 = $wshell.SendKeys('^+C')
            }
        }
        
        # Calculate the meeting end time and check if it's time to end the call
        $meetingEnd = $meeting.End.AddMinutes(9) # End the call 9 minutes after the scheduled end time of the meeting
        if ($currentTime -ge $meeting.End -and $currentTime -lt $meetingEnd) {
            # Check if the call is still active
            $callStatus = (Get-Content -Tail 100 $Log | Select-String -Pattern "TeamsCallStateIdle")
            if (!$callStatus) {
                # Call disconnected before the end time, recall the person
                $teamsarray = (Get-Process *teams*).Id
                foreach ($obj in $teamsarray) {
                    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
                    $Result = $wshell.SendKeys('{ESC}')
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # Wait for 1 minute before checking again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get meetings from a Team Outlook calendar.  The error is probably occurring in one of your scripts.  Maybe try the code at following : https://morgantechspace.com/2021/09/export-teams-and-outlook-calendar-events-using-powershell.html?force_isolation=true